# Image not found, but only sometimes

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-roles

After I migrated my site from AzureWebsites to a Azure Cloud Service, i'm having some issues with the migration and I think are related to IIS (and my lack of expertise of it).

The issue is some times i can't display a image that works just fine. One test method to get that is to refresh many times the image's url and sometimes I'm forward to PageNotFound.

I've an url path for images

```
/Clients/{id}/Images
```

to get the avatar, which is the same relative path for the folders.

I already gave full permissions, ignored this route to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you by chance letting your clients upload images directly to your IIS machines?  If so, do remember that Azure Cloud Service Roles run on distributed machines... so, if one of the web servers gotten the image to its local store, the others did not.

Thus, you want to make sure you store your uploaded content on shared resource, in Azure's case the best place is Blob storage.

HTH

Comment: Hmm. I guess that is the scenario. This role has 2 instance, so that makes sense. I will try azure's storage and give feedback later.

But what would be the best option? Just set the url link pointing to Azure blog? Can I do that with private permissions?

Comment: Yes, every blob can be set to private, and then you can add a *Shared Access Signature* to grant temporary public access. You then embed that url in your web page (probably generating a fresh Shared Access Signature every time you render the page).

Comment: To add to my and Dave's comments: I would suggest that if your Role contains production data, that you RDP into the instances /asap/ and get backup copies of those images.  Azure reimages Role instances on a regular basis and all of the local data is gone.